# UTM source getting overriden with referral when going to subdomain

Tags: google-analytics

I have a site http://test.com. Potential customers are sent to that site with AdWords with a UTM source, so for example, http://test.com?utm_source=adwords. Now if the customers decide to register, they are sent to a page at http://register.test.com. I've configured Google Analytics to work cross domain using `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.mysite.com']);`, but the problem I'm having is that my source gets lost and replaced with a referral to the original domain when I go to the subdomain's page. I tried adding a `_gaq.push(['_addIgnoredRef', 'ekomobi.com']);`, but that only causes my source to be set to `(direct)`.

I will be trying to save the `__utmz` cookie's value and restore it on the other domain, but are there any other proper solutions to the problem of the UTM source getting overriden by the referrer on a domain change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have cross-domain tracking correctly implemented, you should see the original utm parameter when you get to the register page. For cross domain tracking to work, BOTH top-level domain and subdomain must have `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.mysite.com']);,`.

Comment: Ahh of course. I saw the cookies were set to the proper domain so didn't bother doing it on the top level domain, but it seems to have helped the situation. Thanks!